# Unbolding part of the selected Text not working

Tags: javascript, java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to find an answer for unbolding the selected part of the text from other unbolded text but it is unbolding the whole text in the line as shown in the picture. I posted this question a few time but nobody can provide me with the correct answer. I am unbolding the sentence "I am using" but when hit the but it unbolds the whole line. Please help.

[image]

here is the code I am using.

```
private void boldText(){
  int selectionStartb = texto.getSelectionStart();
  int selectionEndb = texto.getSelectionEnd();
  if (selectionStartb > selectionEndb) {
      int temp = selectionEndb;
      selectionEndb = selectionStartb;
      selectionStartb = temp;
  }
  if (selectionEndb > selectionStartb) {
      Spannable str = texto.getText();
      boolean BL = false;
      StyleSpan[] styleSpans;
      styleSpans = str.getSpans(selectionStartb, selectionEndb, StyleSpan.class);
      // If the selected text-part already has BOLD style on it, then
      // we need to disable it
      for (int i = 0; i < styleSpans.length; i++) {
          if (styleSpans[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD) {
              str.removeSpan(styleSpans[i]);
              BL = true;
          }
      }
      // Else we set BOLD style on it
      if (!BL) {
          str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), selectionStartb, selectionEndb,
                  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
      }

  }
```

}

Comment: I suspect that the span being returned for selected text, really spans the whole text, as it is one span. Therefore when you remove it, the whole text is being unbolded. You will have to first check the range of each span, and if it includes some of the unselected text, you will have to change it, instead of removing it.

Comment: How can I do this. Can you please explain me with the code?

Comment: Why don't you use some ready made libraries? This is what I found listed; Android RTEditor: https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor RichEditor-Android: https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android The source code is available, and has Apache license, so you can use and adjust it tough your liking.