# how to show html.fromhtml text in recyclerview from database android

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am able to save and retrieve the rich text (bold, italic, color) to and from the database into the editor. But when I try to show the rich text in the recyclerview, it shows me only plain text and not the styled text (color, bold etc). How can I do this? Thanks

Showing text in the recyclerview

```
String texto_sin_html = Html.fromHtml(list.get(position).getTexto()).toString();
    holder.texto.setText(texto_sin_html);
```

saving text to database

```
String almostSameText = Html.toHtml(texto.getEditableText()).toString();
                    base.modificarNota(titulo.getText().toString().trim(), almostSameText, id);
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be;

```
holder.texto.setText(Html.fromHtml(list.get(position).getTexto()));
```

without the `toString()`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My problem solved. Just missing this little detail. Can you please help me with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53147099/5700719). I know I am missing little detail here also [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53147099/5700719)